# RewriteRule переопределить под nginx

Tags: nginx, php

Всем доброго времени суток. У меня возникла небольшая проблемка по работе с сайтом. Сисадмин ушел в отпуск и приходится самому ковырять проблемки на сервере.  Проблема заключается в следующем: Ранее сайт работал под управлением `Apache2`. С недавних пор,  в виду необходимости, перевели его под управление `nginx + php-fastcgi`. Сайт работает нормально. Но возникла проблема с отображением превьюх картинок. Они обрабатываются специальным контроллером. Для этого в файле .`htaccess` было прописано следующее:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production

RewriteEngine On

#RewriteRule ^.*(files/.*[\.JPG|\.jpg|\.JPEG|\.jpeg|\.GIF|\.gif|\.PNG|\.png])/(w=.*)$ /tools/imagepreview/?$2&f=/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*[\.JPG|\.jpg|\.JPEG|\.jpeg|\.GIF|\.gif|\.PNG|\.png])/(w=.*)$ /tools/imagepreview/?$2&f=/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

<IfModule mod_filter.c>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
```

Моя проблема заключается в том, чтобы правильно переопределить `location` для картинок в `nginx`. Помогите кто чем может.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А оно вообще работает?  

    [\.JPG|\.jpg|\.JPEG|\.jpeg|\.GIF|\.gif|\.PNG|\.png]
Можно упростить до:  

    [.JjPpGgEeIiFfNn|]

Comment: Работает все под Apache2. Под Nginx нет. В этом собственно и проблема. Нужно не упростить, а правильно определить location для nginx.

Comment: Спасибо а ответ. Немного покопался и решил проблему. Нужно было всего на всего перед самой первой секцией location прописать:
rewrite ^/(.*[.JPG|.jpg|.JPEG|.jpeg|.GIF|.gif|.PNG|.png])/(w=.*)$ /tools/imagepreview/index.php?$2&f=/$1 last;

Comment: Я же Вам дал правильное выражение :)  
Человек писавший исходное выражение не совсем понимал как их писать, поэтому я и спросил про работоспособность.

Answer (score 1):

Не силен в nginx, но если не ошибаюсь, то строку с rewrite нужно поместить либо в server, либо в `location /`

```
server {
    ...
    rewrite ^(.*\.(?:jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|bmp|BMP|gif|GIF|png|PNG))(w=.*)$ /tools/imagepreview/?$2&f=$1 last;
    ...
}
```

Так же скорее всего регулярные выражения не чувствительны к регистру, поэтому капсовые расширения файлов можно убрать.

Comment: Сделал ответом, раз помогло.